# How can i get issues assotiated contacts, by using redmine API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, redmine

Steps I've made:

1. created issue.
2. add contacts to issue using browser.
3. I can see issue have that contact, when I use the browser. 3.

I have tried including all possibles: attachments, relations, journals
When I'm trying to receive information about issue by API - I can get all fields, but there is no information about contact I have added.
I receive all journal, attachments.

Comment: Contacts are not a core feature of Redmine. There are various plugins though which add this concept (and which have different ways to access this via the API) Which plugin are you using?

Comment: Thank you for reply. you helped me. appear that we use easy_contacts plugin. so i can go/easy_contacts/project id, and get all of contacts assotiated with current project. but there is no record about issue, which thoose contacts connected with